# Difference between $P(f(x,w)>0)→1$ at any $x$ and $P(\inf(f(x,w))>0)\to1$ when dimension grows

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, random-functions

Let $T:=[-1,1]^{n-1}\times (0,1]$. Let

$$f_n(x_1,\cdots,x_n,w_1,\cdots,w_n):=g(x_1,w_1)+\cdots+g(x_n,w_n)=\sum_{i=1}^ng(x_i,w_i),$$
where

(i) $w_1,\cdots,w_n$ are i.i.d. Gaussian random variables

(ii) $g(x_i,w_i)$ is a smooth function ($g\in C^\infty$)

(iii) $\mathbb{E}g(x_i,w_i)>0$

(iv) $\inf_{(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in T}\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^ng(x_i,w_i))=0$

My question: is there any difference between the following two?

(1) for any $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in T$, we have $$P(\sum_{i=1}^ng(x_i,w_i)>0)\rightarrow 1$$ when $n$ goes to infinity.

(2) $$P\big(\inf_{(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in T}\sum_{i=1}^ng(x_i,w_i)>0\big)\rightarrow 1$$ when $n$ goes to infinity.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: What is $\vec x^*$?

Comment: "When $n$ goes to infinity"?  So you have a whole family of functions $f$, one for each $n$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis sorry for the confusion, I re-edited my question. I hope this time is much clear.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar yes, $f$ is a random function $X_{t\in T\subset R^n}$ and its dimension $n$ grows

Comment: What could $X_{t\in T}$ possibly mean?

Comment: Also, you should write $f_n$ instead of $f$, as Gerald Edgar noted. You cannot have the same function have different numbers of arguments. Also, there is no such thing as the dimension of a function. Also, what is your $\inf$ taken over? Also, you cannot write things like $X_{t\in T}:=\cdots$; I guess you meant here $X_t:=\cdots$ with $t:=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in T$.

Comment: Also, are there any conditions on $f_n$, such as continuity?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you so much for pointing out these issues! I rewrote $f$ as a summation of $n$ terms of $g$ functions. And, $\inf_{\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}\in T}f$ is the infimum of $f$ over $T$, thus it is a random variable. $g$ is smooth function, thus so as $f$.

Comment: The (2) implies (1) since the infimum is a smaller random variable. But I am not sure whether (1) implies (2). If there is a counterexample, it will likely come from the non-compactness of $T$ and thus the possibility of the infimum being zero eg. the g to be heading to zero as we head to the boundary.

Comment: What is $f$ now? And, again,what is your $\inf$ taken over in $\inf\mathbb{E}(f)$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis $f$ is $\sum_{i=1}^ng(x_i,w_i)$, and $\inf \mathbb{E}(f)$ is $\inf\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^ng(x_i,w_i))$ over all $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in T$. sorry for the confusion, I've changed my notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trivial counterexample:
$$g(x,w):=x.$$

Then convergence (1) holds but convergence (2) does not.

On the other hand, of course, convergence (2) always implies convergence (1).

Comment: thank you! Other than '$T$ is compact' (then $\inf=\min$), is there other condition that we could add such that (1) implies (2)?

Comment: @happyle : You can see we have worked quite a bit to make the conditions sensible. But what can sensibly be added, I don't know.

Comment: thanks! this is already very helpful.